# Configuring manual python library installations

Tags: arcpy, installation, anaconda

Windows 7.  My python path reads:

C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts

The end of my user path reads exactly the same thing.

Yet, when I try to install libraries - for example, the requests library:

**python setup.py install**

I get:

*C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2 not found*

I don't understand. I uninstalled ArcGIS 10.2, have removed all current user registry keys (I don't have full admin privileges), and my path variables don't reference the 10.2 installation at all.

When I bring up the python console in ArcMap and then type "import requests" it says "No module named requests."

What I need is to configure my command line installs to by default go into **C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4** for accessibility within Spyder,

and use the *--prefix* install option to send them to **C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4** to access the same libraries from within ArcMap, which confusingly only uses 32 bit in foreground.

Comment: Might seem like a silly question but have you restarted your machine?

Comment: @GeoSharp: not silly. but yes i have.